# Request-response using Netty or other lightweight NIO library

Tags: java, networking, io, netty

I'm developing a system that requires fast communication between two multithreaded applications through the network. Semantically, one application is a client that continuously does RMI calls to another application (server). I suspect that a lightweight library like Netty is more suitable for this task than a heavyweight approach like Tomcat/HTTPClient because of performance reasons. However, Netty is inherently asynchronous and it seems that it's quite difficult to properly implement RMI or request-response invocations on top of it.

Is there way to do request-response calls and, at the same time, leverage high Netty performance without development of error-prone customizations? Are there alternatives to Netty  that are more suitable for this task?

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Netty I'm afraid, but I used [JBoss Remoting](http://www.jboss.org/jbossremoting) for this task  - it supports a variety of protocols 
. You can also look [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossremoting/docs/guide/2.5/html/chapter-adding-new-transport.html) about  JBoss remoting and nio

Answer (score 0):

You could use an embedded GlassFish server and EJBs, which hide a lot of the low-level RMI details.

Comment: Such as? *RMI* hides a lot of the low-level RMI details.

Comment: ? remote EJB uses RMI under the hood, but it's much easier than using "raw" RMI.